# import css after less file

Tags: css, import, less

Here is my less file:

```
@import "app.less";
@import (inline) "rtl.css";
```

when I compile it (using WinLESS), it outputs the following:

```
// content of rtl.css
// content of app.less then
```

I mean the css import statement, which coming later in less file, comes first in compiled css. Why it happen?

Comment: Check if this [Less GitHub thread](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/484) helps.

Comment: Feels a bit wierd to add that as answer mate because I did nothing there other than check the Less GitHub page.

Comment: @Harry: OK, but it's just for making this thread useful, and following forum rules. (I posted it, wait for 2 days, and then mark it as accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

As Harry said, there is a [issue on github](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/484), which says because of CSS limits, any `@import` should placed before any other contents at the CSS file. ([W3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#at-import))

A simple solution is changing CSS file extension to `.less`. Or put `(less)` after `@import` keyword in the statement:
`@import (less) "rtl.css"` to make LESS knowing it as a LESS file. ([LESS Import Options](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options))